# it does not work when I change dns in /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

I temporarily moved into new apartment with modem in hallway that it is open and when I connect needs login for access to internet and I do login and I have access to internet but when I change dns from /etc/resolv.conf it does not use that as I did in my home
but I can change dns in my phone

Comment: which ubuntu version ?

Comment: my ubuntu version is 19.04

Comment: you should configure your dns from the network manager applet and keep the /etc/resolv.conf to default